# hsl with alpha channel separated by a slash

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors, hsl

I was sure that the proper way to use `hsla()` is something like

```
background: hsla(0deg, 100%, 50%, 0.5); /* The same as rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); */
```

However, if I create a paragraph with `background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)` and shift-click that color in Chrome DevTools (Ctrl+Shift+I), the color is converted to

```
hsl(0deg 100% 50% / 50%);
```

Notice that the alpha channel is now separated by a slash and the name of a function is `hsl` rather than `hsla`.

Neither w3schools nor MDN mention this notation.

Why Chrome use it?

Comment: I tried to recreate your code in both Firefox and Chrome and it works as intended.

Comment: it's the new syntax and soon you should use it and forget the old one